# Is self-call possible using Android

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am developing an android application where I need to have an IVR type system. The person should get a call from the application and some questions will be asked and the person has to answer those questions. These answers should be saved somewhere. Is a self call possible?

If not, is there a way to play and record at the same time. I will send a long ring notification to the user and when he responds to the notification, I want to play an mp3 file as well record what user is saying. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is a self call possible?

No, sorry.

> I want to play an mp3 file as well record what user is saying. How can I do that?

Use `MediaPlayer` and `MediaRecorder`, presumably. Or `AudioTrack` and `AudioRecord`.