# How to make a self phone call which plays mp3 when answered?

Tags: android, mp3

I'm trying to make an an android app whereby if the user answers the phone call the mp3 file will start and the voice of the call will be the mp3 file.

Meaning when the app is triggered, it'll make a phone call to itself and when you answer it, the mp3 file will act as the voice behind the phone call.

I know how to make a simple phone call app, but I can't get it to call itself nor making the mp3 file play as the voice from the other side of the phone. Any guides on how to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question about having a phone call itself was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915816/is-self-call-possible-using-android), and says that this is not possible (which makes sense).  As recommended there as well, your best bet is to probably use MediaPlayer to play the MP3 file to the user, and make the application look like a phone app if it really needs to be like a call.

Comment: Oh I saw that post but seeing that post was made in 2010 I was hoping that there'll be a newer solution to this problem... But from my searches there doesn't seem to be any other solution rather than making my own phone app lookalike... But I'm still hoping someone can answer this without using this method :D

Comment: Also I just wanna know whether is this app also making their own phone app lookalike? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.app.fakecall&hl=en

Comment: This probably won't be doable just because the phone would have to be making a call and receiving a call at the same time, which doesn't sound like it would be possible.

As for that app, yes it is, as the phone application that actually makes calls never actually opens.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! it's kind of disappointing that there's no newer solutions but you helped to answer my doubts :D Have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry there doesn't seem to be an actual solution to it!